# Compact command line argument parser

Tags: c#, parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, console

So, I decided to write my own little command line argument parser for various other projects I work on. I am aware that there are many good command line parser libraries, but I did wrote my own anyway (practice & implementation specific reasons).

The parser works fine, but I have a feeling that it can be improved a lot, mainly the following things come to mind

1. Mainly the actual parser, *CommandLineParser.cs*. It seems very badly structured and I find it hard to read myself.
2. Abstraction. I wonder if I can abstract it a bit more without making it a pain to use? Maybe by introducing some interfaces?
3. Naming. I went with *Option* for the command line switch and with *Value* for the possible parameters. Are my methods/classes self-descriptive?
4. Optimizations. I am sure there are segments that can be done more efficiently, mainly in `CommandLineParser.ParseArguments(string[] args)`

A couple of things to note:

1. I'd like to keep the structure for the *CommandLineValue.cs* and *CommandLineOption.cs* mostly the same as they are part of a plugin architecture to communicate command line arguments between the plugins and the main application.
2. No usage of Attributes to store the command line options.
3. I did write a couple of unit tests to verify the parsers functionality. Despite them being not the main class to review, I am appreciate feedback there too :)

**Parser:**

```
public class CommandLineParser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines all possible command line options the plugin can can process
    /// </summary>
    public List<CommandLineOption> SupportedOptions { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the commandline parser with a list of commandline options the plugin exposes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="supportedOptions"></param>
    public CommandLineParser(List<CommandLineOption> supportedOptions)
    {
        SupportedOptions = supportedOptions;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Parse the command line arguments and returns a list of commandline values that can be passed to the
    /// plugin for further processing. The function also handles invalid amount and/or format of options, values
    /// as well as missing required arguments etc
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments to parse</param>
    /// <returns>A list of parsed commandline values + options</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCommandLineOptionException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="InsufficientCommandLineValuesException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidCommandLineValueException"></exception>
    /// <exception cref="MissingRequiredCommandLineOptionException"></exception>
    public IEnumerable<CommandLineValue> ParseArguments(string[] args)
    {
        var result = new List<CommandLineValue>();

        if (args.Length == 0)
            return Enumerable.Empty<CommandLineValue>();


        // Process all command line arguments
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            CommandLineOption option = null;
            if (!IsSupportedOption(args[i], out option))
                throw new InvalidCommandLineOptionException($"{args[i]} is not a valid command line option");

            // Verify if the option expects additional values
            if (HasAdditionalValues(option))
            {
                // Check if enough additional values are given
                int additionalValues = option.ParameterTypes.Count;
                if (i + additionalValues + 1 > args.Length)
                    throw new InsufficientCommandLineValuesException(
                        $"{args[i]} expects {additionalValues} values.");

                // Check if the additional values are in the right format
                // ToDo: Find more elegant solution
                var values = args.ToList().GetRange(i + 1, i + additionalValues).ToList();
                var types = option.ParameterTypes.ToList();

                var castedValues = values.Zip(types, (value, type) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw new InvalidCommandLineValueException(
                            $"Cannot cast between value {value} to type {type}");
                    }
                });

                result.Add(new CommandLineValue(option, castedValues.ToList()));

                // Increase i to skip to the next option
                i += additionalValues;
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(new CommandLineValue(option, null));
            }
        }

        // Collect required arguments
        List<string> requiredOptions = new List<string>();
        foreach (var option in SupportedOptions)
        {
            if (option.Required)
                foreach (var tag in option.Tags)
                {
                    requiredOptions.Add(tag);
                }
        }

        // Check that no required arguments are missing (or occur twice)
        var missing = GetMissingRequiredArgs<string>(requiredOptions, args.ToList());
        if (missing == null)
            return result;
        throw new MissingRequiredCommandLineOptionException(
            $"The required arument(s) {string.Join(",", missing)} occured multiple times");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check that all required options are used and that they (the required options) dont occur multiple times are no duplicates
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="required">A list of required options</param>
    /// <param name="arguments"><The args to check</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Any primitive type</typeparam>
    /// <exception cref="MissingRequiredCommandLineOptionException">Thrown if any distinct required arguments exist more then once</exception>
    /// <returns>A list of missing required args, if any. Null if none are missing.</returns>
    static List<T> GetMissingRequiredArgs<T>(List<T> required, List<T> arguments)
    {
        // convert to Dictionary where we store the required item as a key against count for an item
        var requiredDict = required.ToDictionary(k => k, v => 0);

        foreach (var item in arguments)
        {
            if (!requiredDict.ContainsKey(item))
                continue;
            requiredDict[item]++; // if we have required, adding to count
            if (requiredDict[item] <= 1)
                continue;
            throw new DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException(
                $"Required option {item} appeared more than once!");
        }

        var result = new List<T>();
        // now we are checking for missing items
        foreach (var key in requiredDict.Keys)
        {
            if (requiredDict[key] == 0)
            {
                result.Add(key);
            }
        }

        return result.Any() ? result : null;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Verify if given option is part of the supported options
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if the option is supported otherwise false</returns>
    private bool IsSupportedOption(string optionIdentifier, out CommandLineOption option)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < SupportedOptions.Count; index++)
        {
            var supportedOption = SupportedOptions[index];
            if (supportedOption.Tags.Any(tag => tag == optionIdentifier))
            {
                option = SupportedOptions[index];
                return true;
            }
        }

        option = null;
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if a command line option has multiple values or if its just a flag
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="option">Commandlineoption to check</param>
    /// <returns>true if the option has multiple values, otherwise false</returns>
    private bool HasAdditionalValues(CommandLineOption option)
    {
        var noParameters = option.ParameterTypes == null || option.ParameterTypes.Count == 0;
        return !noParameters;
    }
}
```

**Classes to store commandline information:**

```
public class CommandLineOption
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier of the commandline option, e.g. -h or --help
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the commandline option
    /// </summary>
    public string Description { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if the argument is optional or required
    /// </summary>
    public bool Required { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Types of the additional provided values such as directory paths, values etc ..
    /// </summary>
    public IList<Type> ParameterTypes { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new true/false commandline option 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tags">Identifier of the command line option</param>
    /// <param name="description">Description of the command line option</param>
    /// <param name="required">Indicates if the command line option is optional or not</param>
    public CommandLineOption(IEnumerable<string> tags, string description, bool required = false)
    {
        Tags = tags.ToList();
        Description = description;
        Required = required;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new true/false commandline option 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tags">Identifier of the command line option</param>
    /// <param name="description">Description of the command line option</param>
    /// <param name="required">Indicates if the command line option is optional or not</param>
    public CommandLineOption(IEnumerable<string> tags, string description, bool required = false, params Type[] parameterTypes):
        this(tags, description, required)
    {
        ParameterTypes = new List<Type>(parameterTypes);
    }

}
```

```
public class CommandLineValue : IEqualityComparer<CommandLineValue>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds all the values specified after a command line option
    /// </summary>
    public IList<object> Values { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The command line option the value(s) belong to
    /// </summary>
    public CommandLineOption Option { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the values that correspond to a commandline option
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="option">The commandline option the values refer to</param>
    /// <param name="values">The values that are stored</param>
    public CommandLineValue(CommandLineOption option, IList<object> values)
    {
        Option = option;
        Values = values;
    }


    public bool Equals(CommandLineValue x, CommandLineValue y)
    {
        if (x.Option.Description == y.Option.Description &&
            x.Option.Required == y.Option.Required &&
            x.Option.Tags.SequenceEqual(y.Option.Tags) &&
            x.Option.ParameterTypes.SequenceEqual(y.Option.ParameterTypes) &&
            x.Values.SequenceEqual(x.Values))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CommandLineValue obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Custom Exception Classes:**

```
public class DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException : Exception
{
    public DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class InsufficientCommandLineValuesException : Exception
{
    public InsufficientCommandLineValuesException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class InvalidCommandLineOptionException : Exception
{
    public InvalidCommandLineOptionException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class InvalidCommandLineValueException : Exception
{
    public InvalidCommandLineValueException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class MissingRequiredCommandLineOptionException : Exception
{
    public MissingRequiredCommandLineOptionException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

**Unit Tests:**

```
public class CommandLineParserTests
{     

    [Fact]
    public void ParseDuplicateRequiredArguments()
    {
        var args = new[] {"--randomize", "-o", "/home/user/Documents", "--randomize", "-d"};
        var supportedOptions = new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-r", "--randomize"},
                "Random flag",
                true),
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-o", "--output-directory"},
                "Specifies the output directory",
                true,
                typeof(string)),
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-d", "--dummy"},
                "Just another unused flag"),
        };

        var parser = new CommandLineParser(supportedOptions);
        Assert.Throws<DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException>(() =>
            parser.ParseArguments(args)
        );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseMissingRequiredArguments()
    {
        var args = new[] {"--randomize", "--output-directory", "/home/user/Documents"};
        var supportedOptions = new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-r", "--randomize"},
                "Random flag"),
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-o", "--output-directory"},
                "Specifies the output directory",
                true,
                typeof(string)),
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-d", "--dummy"},
                "Just another unused flag"),
        };

        var parser = new CommandLineParser(supportedOptions);
        Assert.Throws<MissingRequiredCommandLineOptionException>(() =>
            parser.ParseArguments(args)
        );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseMatchingTypeCommandLineValues()
    {
        var args = new[] {"--log", "info", "1337", "3.1415"};
        var supportedOptions = new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-l", "--log"},
                "Logs info from exactly three data sources",
                false,
                typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(float))
        };

        var parser = new CommandLineParser(supportedOptions);

        var expectedValue = new CommandLineValue(new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-l", "--log"},
                "Logs info from exactly three data sources",
                false,
                typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(float)),
            new object[] {"info", 1337, (float) 3.1415});

        var actualValue = parser.ParseArguments(args).ToList()[0];
        Assert.True(expectedValue.Equals(actualValue, expectedValue));

    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseMismatchingTypeCommandLineValues()
    {
        var args = new[] {"--log", "info", "1337", "3.1415"};
        var supportedOptions = new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-l", "--log"},
                "Logs info from exactly three data sources",
                false,
                typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(long)),
        };
        var parser = new CommandLineParser(supportedOptions);

        Assert.Throws<InvalidCommandLineValueException>(() =>
            parser.ParseArguments(args)
        );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseInsufficientCommandLineValues()
    {
        var args = new[] {"-l", "info", "info2"};
        var supportedOptions = new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(
                new[] {"-l", "--log"},
                "Logs info from exactly three data sources",
                false, typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string)),
        };
        var parser = new CommandLineParser(supportedOptions);

        Assert.Throws<InsufficientCommandLineValuesException>(() =>
            parser.ParseArguments(args)
        );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseInvalidCommandLineOption()
    {
        var args = new[] {"--force"};
        var supportedOptions = new List<CommandLineOption>
        {
            new CommandLineOption(new[] {"-h", "--help"}, "Show the help menu"),
        };
        var parser = new CommandLineParser(supportedOptions);

        Assert.Throws<InvalidCommandLineOptionException>(() =>
            parser.ParseArguments(args)
        );
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseNoCommandLineOptions()
    {
        var args = new string[] { };
        var parser = new CommandLineParser(null);
        var result = parser.ParseArguments(args);

        Assert.Equal(Enumerable.Empty<CommandLineValue>(), result);
    }
}
```

I appreciate all suggestions. Feel free to be very nitpicky. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Design Issues

There are a couple of issues concerning your design.

#### Lack of specification

It is unclear which features should be supported by your API. This makes reviewing a bit fuzzy.

#### Dependencies

The parser depends on arguments already pre-parsed correctly by a shell. This limits the control you have over command line parsing.

> `var args = new[] {"--log", "info", "1337", "3.1415"};`

Consider breaking free from the shell and take on pre-parsing yourself.

```
var args = "--log info 1337 3.1415";  // <- unparsed command line string
```

#### Pollution

The API mixes language structs with user-defined options.

> `new CommandLineOption(new[] {"-l", "--log"}`

You do not want `-` and `--` to be part of the `Tags`. These are delimiters in the lexing phase of your parser. By seperating lexing from parsing, you could extend the API more fluently by allowing other command line languages. For instance `/log`.

---

### Review

#### Exception Classes

Define a base class for all your exceptions `CommandLineException`. This way, you allow calling code to determine the granularity of exception handling. Since you make several custom exceptions, take advantage of storing some data on them. `DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException` could store the duplicate option, and so on. Also provide constructors that take an inner exception.

```
public class DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException : CommandLineException
{
    public CommandLineOption Option { get; }
    // include more constructors ..
    public DuplicateRequiredCommandLineOptionException(
        string messageCommandLineOption  option) : base(message) { Option = option; }
}
```

#### CommandLineOption & CommandLineValue

You have addressed you don't want to see too many changes for legacy reasons. I do propose to override the default `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on both classes and substitute `IEqualityComparer` with `IEquatable`. This way, you could improve your code.

```
 public bool Equals(CommandLineValue other)
 {
     return Option.Equals(other.Option) && Values.SequenceEqual(other.Values);
 }
```

#### CommandLineParser

You have indicated yourself you have problems parsing a flattened list to a hierarchical structure. There are common techniques for handling such situations. Have a look at [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). You should create a syntax tree from the provided `string[] args`. This can be done with a *Stack* and *Iterator*. There are tons of examples online how to create an AST.

> ```
> // Check if the additional values are in the right format
> // ToDo: Find more elegant solution
> var values = args.ToList().GetRange(i + 1, i + additionalValues).ToList();
> var types = option.ParameterTypes.ToList();
> ```

The second issue is - what I called *pollution* before - the lack of seperation of concerns. Your API is basically a simple [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). The link shows you it's good practice to provide the following phases when building a compiler:

- pre-processing
- lexing
- parsing
- optimizing
- pretty printing

Your API should definitely include lexing and parsing as seperate phases.

- lexing: create command line tokens and strip all the keywords and language-specific delimiters
- parsing: create an AST from the lexed tokens, then create `CommandLineValue` instances from the AST.

---

#### Conclusion

In the end, the quality of the API depends on a good specification covered by many unit tests. I feel you haven't established this yet.

Comment: Thanks. You really got me interested on compiler creation now :D
I'll try to write my own lexer and parser.

Comment: Good to hear! Looking forward to a follow-up question ;-)

Comment: I took your suggestions and made a follow up question. It is now using a lexer and a parser :) You can find it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222550/compact-command-line-argument-parser-revisited